# Implement Active Directory Group in Asp.Net CORE 3.x

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

Asp.net CORE 3.x :
The authentication is working fine with Azure Active Directory.
Now, i would like to implement the authorization a specific AD Group for all routes.
How to implement this authorization ? steps by steps with Asp.NET Core ?

```
   public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAD", options));

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        });

        services.AddControllers();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute().RequireAuthorization();
            //endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

}

Thank you for you help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groups claims` in Azure AD ,  config the your application in azure portal to receive group claims by editing the manifest :

```
{
  ...
  "errorUrl": null,
  "groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup",
  ...
}
```

ID token issued from Azure AD will include the current user's groups id list in `groups` claim , then in asp.net core application , you can restrict the access by :

```
services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser().RequireClaim("groups", "YourGroupID")
            .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    });
```

Note : From [document](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/886f2ad2bf6add922c7998fb592e3d4088f9cf4e/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-2-Groups) :

> If a user is member of more groups than the overage limit (150 for SAML tokens, 200 for JWT tokens), then the Microsoft Identity Platform does not emit the groups claim in the token. Instead, it includes an overage claim in the token that indicates to the application to query the Graph API to retrieve the user’s group membership.