# User under sub group of the AAD group, failed to authenticate with Azure AD Policy

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.2

We have below app roles in the AAD app manifest json file:

```
  "appRoles": [
    {
        "allowedMemberTypes": [
            "User"
        ],
        "description": "Security group for Test.",
        "displayName": "Test",
        "id": "5500dd65-c64b-400e-98dd-8e255563aefe",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "lang": null,
        "origin": "Application",
        "value": "Test"
    }
],
```

My controller is decorated with

```
[Authorize(Policy = "Test")]
```

and we have assigned an AAD group `GroupA` to this app role. We found that only `user1` and `user2` who are under `GroupA` have the access to my controller, but for `user3` and `user4` who are under `GroupB`, they don't have access. Any ideas?

```
GroupA
    -User1
    -User2
    -GroupB
            -User3
            -User4
    -GroupC
```

Answer (score 0):

That is currently not possible in Azure AD . Currectly role assignment only works with direct group membership not transitive group membership .

You can vote on the [feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/18678670-support-inheriting-roles-in-nested-groups) .

As a workaround , you can check the [groups claims](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58177552/5751404) in your application .